# RSS Viewer Can't load

Tags: 2010, rss

My RSS Viewer always in "Retrieving Data" mode but can't show anything. It just says that it retrieves data. In Sharepoint Designer 2010 on the RSS Viewer area a message displays. It says ;

> "The server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data from
>   the data source. Check the format and content of your query and try
>   again. If the problem persists, contact the server administrator."

Why does it happen?

My example rss url : http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml

Comment: Does your sharepoint servers have access to the internet? The RSS webpart is loading it's data on the server not on the client.

Comment: Yes , it has. I tried to add <system.net>
for proxy server to web.config too. But it didn't work.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and tried configuring a proxy etc. Voted up!

Comment: I was able to fix my error - in this case it was due to the feed being on the local intranet. I had to use powershell - won't fix it with the url you stated since that is public but if it happens to be internal reply and I'll post the script.